# Object PDF doesn't render in IE, but works in Chrome

Tags: html, internet-explorer, pdf, object-tag

I am embedding a PDF via the Object tag like so:

```
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMgCjEgMCBvYmoKPDwKL1BhZ2VzIDIgMCBSCi9UeXBlIC9DYXRhbG9nCj4+CmVuZG9iagoyIDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9UeXBlIC9QYWdlcwovS2lkcyBbIDMgMCBSIF0KL0NvdW50IDEKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjMgMCBvYmoKPDwKL1R5cGUgL1BhZ2UKL1BhcmVudCAyIDAgUgovUmVzb3VyY2VzIDw8Ci9YT2JqZWN0IDw8IC9JbTAgOCAwIFIgPj4KL1Byb2NTZXQgNiAwIFIgPj4KL01lZGlhQm94IFswIDAgNDAwIDI5MF0KL0Nyb3BCb3ggWzAgMCA0MDAgMjkwXQovQ29udGVudHMgNCAwIFIKL1RodW1iIDExIDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKNCAwIG9iago8PAovTGVuZ3RoIDUgMCBSCj4+CnN0cmVhbQpxCjQwMCAwIDAgMjkwIDAgMCBjbQovSW0wIERvClEKZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVuZG9iago1IDAgb2JqCjMxCmVuZG9iago2IDAgb2JqClsgL1BERiAvVGV4dCAvSW1hZ2VJIF0KZW5kb2JqCjcgMCBvYmoKPDwKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjggMCBvYmoKPDwKL1R5cGUgL1hPYmplY3QKL1N1YnR5cGUgL0ltYWdlCi9OYW1lIC9JbTAKL0ZpbHRlciBbIC9GbGF0ZURlY29kZSBdCi9XaWR0aCA0MDAKL0hlaWdodCAyOTAKL0NvbG9yU3BhY2UgMTAgMCBSCi9CaXRzUGVyQ29tcG9uZW50IDgKL0xlbmd0aCA5IDAgUgo+PgpzdHJlYW0KeNrtnUuS7KoRhlmGZ0zvAm544Al3J2zAA6/AzBzeBUthKWzBI49uhKwkeSQIqVTd5Sj61P9FnJYoAVUnf0k8hDK3DQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD4MloxxsV7BWIq4UpZfa9AePf/88cQyLre7paNF7lcaPtWFQN75W98Q4Qez8DWcvslcp4ndgZV9bpQT3wDuAdbi07ieJZlv+UEWcLsmW3ae+IbwD2ytS6MRi2APKZiuWNBj9fTXR/RGqO03z+OdBGEYHRIe9r4VmJvOLi9SXpQe8KZSsJpZcJGf2P+Bme1simxBWM07bYveLcF1oL18Kn9CHQbcrn7tB/wOu0PJ7his9tyfaTDgfWghPYuCehyM8N5NSfc/j2WOw/tC0CDramTiTRdJKGZUUdLp+9Rj41Obn+ihxd/4yZ6DC515zyJb7svAA2yijbW037Ro1jW1ixBltj4/ra3I+2wKBX6v+0K1OnCCkXx9gWgIY0d/W4s053pY5Yt36WoCTHP6MEZNN3JjNa6+wLQ6I29t7a+s+wxS75LpWFhO3xTD1kV+l0zOqvYvbUN9/TYzNN6aO5rTb8ZZKRVHN1B7uoRn9ODG3GTOwthgx5zhjuII1FmesRWIm991iMNF/2lHj5pHbnZsfvGbtBjSpB3kDR3m8YWUU4D7p/YPJrb5CyirS2JpYHEhR6W6k7FTJr90hvmGack8yjtOBXSwNrSCD2SLHuC2IfSdZSQps/LXLDhzV7ABbZ6KsVl0wCcRug0xN+71LmGfdjO43PxBQAAAH4Yag3ebYZleLcQ0AMAAAD4EtHuI+zyNLxLbHUGpK2TC2NRXSZORNFJy7wP45+pSLfpmPYbPgKa9rYmr7bqElubISQT20QYi+q8LkgWtRmxhsuUmu5VpNtqI/9Z3S2dZg8jb7rEVmd2yUjmWNSkbI4PDUUJ21aPltneeUU8teg4e5eQv+Ej8Nk+gf7/XYIe1OpiCz9b9VEfd4z1lDL1HI+qXB+zikpZQ0p0ie43fATeuLSN9L/uEnRnicUWdjYTzvbmPH3RvOdLTqPK57OKbM7oeUJYJLrf8FEEuTKdE3SLV/VZrDddQ084mj2PpjvjWz2mLRZxtBRInVZUVp+msl2i+w0fhbzvi0Rrhbm1tl0hn3pKflpPaHertKquPcs9VFRyRl7gIBLdb/gkrHy9QCRqK5zO2tAb32tlrHg01RVtl03UaSmpOq2os/xRhg/Uw8jF7DJRbBH5Ey97R4GVCGIs0YqK+5/ND2lPK4IePfLxa58YbZFuIjx+KD0gYVtZ1NbLw5fVv6cV4X7VkdfqThJHW+QlbGpmua5ou8byAJA2JxVdtOez3/CL4+WbUH54LaqMGng57256LY/F/KE6FBXDvm7yZFrRRX9X/IYPwcu+jh97UHUUZ9LWycP9/aov6g7DviLapKKL8aD4DZ9BlO9bxMPLF6UV5gO+e4et9JV0fn9HFjWHYR/XNK0od5LrfIlIiN/wGdgyv0d39y7R2aLMFnpZ1qnU3032G4rqw8uHred8rKhMIYZDQv6Gj6C7ux/nydvsxzAJnghm/5CXsA1F1Zke84ou59s/Sg8AAAAAAAAAAB+PM4a8xNjTDH50nxC0WNgGR3GvxdCrffTC4GkOfZgF6V/BtHXdIRzFfRuXTaPNaRY9m5WSFlUKjuJeRX79eAvmNIs/unsZ9KA3aFMe6PFdVHn2bZ8r1ekRyx0LenwXalzFJPfEa1tpfpvPuIMecBT3MnhtW1Fk5rUtN7+jz7jQ6oCjuBdi+WlSMkKYem1j4+vBZ1xoVcBR3CvhK4Rf4Jh6bev1GHzMpNQGR3EvJLqyHldPvbax+UafcaFVAEdxr8PRH/bpcua1rexNfcalVPpr6/P3Z/SYf+XnYnhjL7y25b25z7iUylU9rcfpV34u2QLxwmtbbX79tR7xOT08HMVNyGtvYzHRxGtbteXMZ1xK5a2Ho7hvw+PzaM69tsXa1nc+43ytAo7iXoiJ3tIAORti4rVN82SI8BkX5PtRcBQHAACfiFqSd1sFekAPAAAAAPxqlLkm7nG1v/LfMc/Xjsy/B0igx1pAj7WAHmsBPdYCeqwF9FgL6LEW0GMtoMdaQI+1gB5rAT3WAnqsBfRYC+ixFtBjLaDHWkCPtYAeawE91gJ6rAX0WAvosRbQYy2gx1pAj7WAHmsBPdYCegAAAACfy1/++OOvf/9z2IC38dv+75//GjbgbZAC//192IC38Rv/6TfgbZDx//P7sAFvI7UY/x424G3sPaq//ePPYQMAAOATSG5Ymz9dTQmOm3IPbzTCEryUkCQQ++GJwk6pXUN3eviZugCTAnLFtGuteu7pEGW3xR/ygQiP019AeVXCDGj/nB7hMnvU0OMLqBQWhfa8DS/Ug3yJh3f/534gKgUu8PueCdXAIp4a3cMoSJqtiRI+zejc9MjoaxS5hTyxp0wpFqso0oVRQ2y1KSrFFjB0QtcTfoynpr0tQR9leI+87XJTyDSXGqTSN1BDRJAcRg2x1eYoPuvj5lrIFT3EU/N9cLVBD5k75JBp7lwPDqMWEFttjmK7uk3Hgx7FhGGeGPSgfZtEMC1U3rG8TV9rEVttTraopig1xWrHeGpXesjcohE/vV+loxqx1eaQmahFp1O6dZjGeGpXesjcwrRneoTu6Lj/8aQzXNW7Pxv4EE/tUg+RW9x6HurhtiEn2LYaBthtzcDuEE/tSg+Zuw32H+hhEFttTrFs3DZptSGemmjpW/i0dk3U3J4nJIPL5eI04tqG2Gpn5ABp2tJfly2T5nmpF0zjtU4PK8Oneb4Yuty0VVrzns2f1CKxmd5wxg2x1QQ1QNreRaIoanm+XcRTy0HSTGkYRPi0lF1vXW4OmeZS3SaHu29FujBqiK0GAAA/F7UY77bHu3m3/aEHAAAAsBJoi9cCeqwF9FgL6LEK3tA8LfRYBKcUrYaDHmsQ0uOTJxeagv8btixLhB5LoHn5AtqPRSjLSaDHGkCPtcgv3eB+tQi5PffQYw1iWjsVMf5YhTwe1NBjEehVAxuhBwAAAAAAAAAA8HKiM/S+vgvOPcpqy8J033tZ8HC68DIcv5wZ3R0vL+XdWV2ehbBfuJoE38VWGfwNPcKgR/YLBz1ehcvv6hPGPcwe+vtV8QuH+9WLoPfBXUl49zB/v9gHfuFeTfEKIPBGa35FvHMXRy+Ra5NdM+hUrPqF06WW07LgHsIHSYZ8ue0fO9pX0l3c3gljnwJbc7OQNyV5Whbc5PBiZUj3L1/NXd3F+XJA+iZR0o/MeVlwl4MeNjm1CtW5XhDefPw2+u7p9TgtC+6ix/uVLme63nqb1gPnepyWBXexY3uupNmlTdVjPU7Lgrt4NYzKT8/xG3rg+vg+RrS4YStOQz07P36+/ZiXBbehHqzn3aC37FRX9JGC8NTn5v2rKC6eeVlwn2iyII6DgQxjCOm+T9f2PyoulP3CleRpWfAEwe6DamN9TqYxdkr07uKiVdp6mpiP7C4uVL9wJXlaFgAAwK8FXI+tBfQAAAAAfi61pdX7YPsIjavtScH5/ix9XRoIaNqJMOxhf4S83/uTgvP9Wfq6NBBUw+xXgp0djo8KUtl4fuxxaSBohgmzBQfndruyKPT4Ms0wxflFtDlER2lcWqb8eJDmcv2+2TPyFG5eqWhKK7Qfc7qF9xA1wrHcA5phPAfgpod6Nj8JsempxkEPra3eLarJJUBeQVIK6vyEVqf9soS01QjHcg8ohqFF7YG2HN7G54ajPAMUmXPgdFVcZoT8OS/gNWR2jqOXIrANNcKx3APa1FIJJJw2+3ls+XD7W/XwvO9ok9ZPl/vYRmEiY80Sc/BOUSMcyz0g9XeNqoGas+e30rpP9Yi8H2gTKV9e5qD5FZDBPVZXIxzLPSCHSjVl9DHMxU71yPuxfsYreelZrbbhmF/UCEdmDyiG0dwq1PGhpXb8KT3S43dezjDkFzVCjwfU0LW5PdD9ALDokT6MEz3a/SpBSx0GPboa4VjuAdUwjg2cG9zNc6zITg/f6+G5mOWPoja1wk6PrkY4lntAM4zOvVPu9uqydor+8lRK0L0eueca6nXgN7K0HvToaoxwLHeNnC/JBuXRmxWHaSHu/pkd9EjjQVc+KgXDoEdfo4NjuUvEiWq5j5VaZZ4HaS21SR91eug0XxJarmDKtEivR18jHMsBAAAAAAAAnoVeuPHv/hGg4E3cYnrwB1YgDcxDfPfPABnMd6wF9FiLdL/y/t0/A2QC2vO18Br9XQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC/kfxICti8KZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVuZG9iago5IDAgb2JqCjMyNDUKZW5kb2JqCjEwIDAgb2JqCi9EZXZpY2VHcmF5CmVuZG9iagoxMSAwIG9iago8PAovRmlsdGVyIFsgL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlIF0KL1dpZHRoIDEwNgovSGVpZ2h0IDc3Ci9Db2xvclNwYWNlIDEwIDAgUgovQml0c1BlckNvbXBvbmVudCA4Ci9MZW5ndGggMTIgMCBSCj4+CnN0cmVhbQp42u2Y+VMbRxbH/6D9bf+CrdR6K+XEVTj2OgfgmNjBa2PsWJaxsIKcgINuJAS6DySQBAIdoPuAEQgEGknI3CBxWxiDEBLi1DmdwcRbu85WflgNrq0tvjU99d50VX/mvXnT0z0AXOhcdRIaj55ZSA7kJiKpSO63nszkPqakDEFYGY3tH24mgro8aL4U8qZ2Yodb28mdvS+dx0j8OBE7wAj1I4fYSWsIlkhJD9PgVXXFBIR7bLtbR8B5btQzPD9yWu+5EWxIRPW+k/Dl9NV4KxWA+ZUSxWBlZd+3zfcfdpbqSssJEKseI1Cyqhd0VlVDFXtmSu5YsTztncd/b3zQgsf3kFgqx92QoAmj5L3uNsNuq81p8A7bfF5dv390zNrnMlqMfc5+4zDcN2C3+DGoDAQBMTgIBwN+2OeD/X5fMAD7/D6f3x8Ioh4Mw4FTc69o0FuNZtmj9RSGVtJmaAuAgM4d6+ud8RqFR0lD2mKaAyCmM8UhDYxAy0WRIrCt07nYFCL5wgQ9euNMUd2Uz8vJylU5I3EXzw0DYLd1CfgLrZMkb5FBUacLBkXWG4hatfJIlCv/ZX+naXyLczDN4762u/irS/oV9wtTviPhhYsCreAs+5LGTQAHFpxu3vwiZ4brf6Y/MncCH/27ob5p/mLYomuXtfpb8nBxJD9ZFWSJXcjqWqpDij6nEb7VR+4IwOjzKQSOrHwfADtSddLOhcHqanHZA8i7+vvdtQ8MTHS4e3Q2agKdWLNbWZB4k40dve9NFF/f77WnHDWj946ADPsN6lVGgPcTt+P1WUQIEDL/Q8z/nbavsxan2wfNDDclYFFHvp4FMcLVwV2JSdcvFWkd3PualcGuSYah+Ngy1pKntUQt64e1byzNJaYylDSHvxUva6zhPi9nPmqpIz38h6T/yqtM0aStwZEX5OeLbOZJeVf1DX35FFieir7cvV9XK/j5DgcnIlA7brlCpYnis7cz4A4ENbDDtaBz63sHe/zLw9DSRNjVa4WsvU7ziKk/bDUHdTOpokkhCo1GZdIYdPRg0mhMGpXOQC/RT8Vg0FEP7aDQyKHigwLJzZ25pcm1hejr6aONiTfrM5O78/7Im6XFrZWpt4cbE0tzMYzeq0F5b8Wzz8n3WpquhQWfSmhff9Z/588/SAi4rp9KlHOCy88qdAVsSJBUX4a71HCbTbuywP1E0Hj9kuPmn6oE+Gol8bJihvtXXFn3BemCdC6kkMXzkvtEQevprF03PDYqX+ADjbfYRl6zS/LMvmrAcV+6MSIV8vlMNpPL5nIZJJfO729vJ3fjqJ/NZzN5JIf25bEBfahISB4c9eyez+D/puVxXSgAY7W7+FellGMAcuX+6ec81sNcFjWOsV1FALD/RWm8jF6IpzJvY+l4Ir51TbWdQA7jsy3J7djpTuowdby5g0VNHDCuaasEo3R84DZR38B5NPuZlYkbbRSKKqbuPlfUkfpe0lzXxUfFg0BKQyZSeGOPL7tKa3k1DWVLX/TXXGm7OmW+G/n7Pd4Tw0gJ5L+2jUX2dlSTsEjseFLjqefruymkuSdO3NMBSvN4w1J9jZbjSdQq54jFf3FRjXBlMj5PLBSJBUKRVCAQndpSiUAmlIkEIoFYLhZK+JIxDEjhAQhyuyHo7Iw29HCiBvTOetcBuQfCWAT1e62rz2fcD5XtJhI/DinaBv/8cUjbzSbSxyEVgtbiNmX/KyosT62/n2U3Jg82AbK/fi4gRM0aF8ezufxJGgHQN0HJhtbPBulCPp3BeEbf+lsApKbEneMPSWNd7Bu2Ov13tp/GVErPAwLG7+zmXwIASMmP2r96wPxefdN4x/LAeb9WdltedrMfW1JBzFlcdZMbzV9VNTdwKntKXdWGSlVrvbb8Wwu2pCQk4ltcQpWO3tSm4fDlFB2/nWnhaTR0Rnca2+wpFYq2tnaFvP2stcsVp00ub1doDzHkDFNa7KclHlfFTt21NZBaAeBk/LeyOwliVn8yzRp9Y3Yo2vN4+CC6YFfzR1ZnZ6FZlvPVgW84Fe7lY0aSUptaJ55yiH0tlFWnjGJnq9kmKtXeOEpSE35hsB1MzLLXZh+hDFVJWPY26qsOmRI2mBrNBjKze6+ej+fRKQtizGKyhUD3qJHtDdmHmBKba54hGB91sBzuw7ZlGW/RxejGLKZ8AeSz+SOkkEeOc/k8ks2g5jGCLspB5hgUTs5pXQ5AbA7Lwv4DIeYF7H6A/bFmbcmPRCqcYL32v9CFLnSh/0f9CjHCsjsKZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVuZG9iagoxMiAwIG9iagoxNjkyCmVuZG9iagoxMyAwIG9iago8PAovTGVuZ3RoIDE0IDAgUgo+PgpzdHJlYW0K////AAAAHx8fPz8/f39/39/fv7+/n5+fX19fGBgYQEBANjY2bGxs/Pz8KCgofn5+hoaG9vb2NDQ08PDwiIiIOjo6cHBwCmVuZHN0cmVhbQplbmRvYmoKMTQgMCBvYmoKNjkKZW5kb2JqCjE1IDAgb2JqCjw8Cj4+CmVuZG9iagoxNiAwIG9iago2OQplbmRvYmoKMTcgMCBvYmoKPDwKL1RpdGxlICgvdG1wL21hZ2ljay1YWFFiZ1ZONikKL0NyZWF0aW9uRGF0ZSAoRDoyMDE0MDExOTExMzQ0MCkKL01vZERhdGUgKEQ6MjAxNDAxMTkxMTM0NDApCi9Qcm9kdWNlciAoSW1hZ2VNYWdpY2sgNi41LjQtNyAyMDEyLTA1LTA3IFExNiBPcGVuTVAgaHR0cDovL3d3dy5pbWFnZW1hZ2ljay5vcmcpCj4+CmVuZG9iagp4cmVmCjAgMTgKMDAwMDAwMDAwMCA2NTUzNSBmIAowMDAwMDAwMDEwIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDAwNTkgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDExOCAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwMzAwIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDAzODMgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDQwMSAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwNDM5IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDA0NjAgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMzg4NyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAzOTA3IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDM5MzUgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwNTc2OCAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA1Nzg5IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDU5MTMgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwNTkzMiAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA1OTU0IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDU5NzMgMDAwMDAgbiAKdHJhaWxlcgo8PAovU2l6ZSAxOAovSW5mbyAxNyAwIFIKL1Jvb3QgMSAwIFIKPj4Kc3RhcnR4cmVmCjYxNjcKJSVFT0YK"
    type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="400">
</object>
```

It works perfectly in Chrome; however, it doesn't show up in IE!

This is the JS Fiddle so you can see for yourself:

http://jsfiddle.net/KGfUm/

How can I make it work in IE and Chrome?

Comment: The fiddle seems to crash the latest FireFox FWIW

Answer (score 1):

Currently PDF can't be displayed in IE without Adobe Reader or some 3rd party plugin. I think this is the cause of issue

Comment: Wow, even in IE 11!?  Which was just released...  Well thanks for your comment.

Comment: Yes, Instead of opening file, it asks user to save file.